# 93 Thunderbird LX priority maintenance?

Tags: engine, ford, automatic-transmission, maintenance

Purchased from first owner that said he had kept the basic rules and procedures for a stored automobile when I come in from out of town and sees a jump start hooked up this is where I knew it was not at all how it is really..I would like to know if there is any suggestions on the order of Maintenance needing to be done to this car that's been sitting for The Last 5 Years most likely without being started up but every year,,?

Answer (score 0):

The "basic" list of "rules and procedures" will vary in detail by the number of people you ask - some will add or remove items as they see fit.

If by "maintenance" you mean what you need to do to put it back on the road then that is one thing, but if you mean to keep it in storage that is a different list.

To put it back in the road, I would start with:

Tires - after 5 years probably best to replace.

Brakes, check for condition ie surface rust, change brake fluid as it is hygroscopic.

Change fluids : oils, coolant..

Check items such as lights & wipers

Bearings : the wheel bearings may have suffered by not moving for a long time, so they could become an early fail...

Edit from suggestion below:
Remove any old fuel and replace with fresh, do this from tank to engine...

Comment: Fluids: also fuel. Whatever is left in the tank won't be the same grade as when it was put in! If the owner really followed "basic procedure" for a 5 year layup, the car should have been on supports not standing on its own wheels, so wheel bearings and suspension springs shouldn't have be affected.

Comment: @alephzero The "if the owner really followed basic procedure", well I would hazard a guess if they had then we would have had a better description in the question as in "this and this and this was done for storage ", but as that detail is not in the question then I have my doiubts. Good point about fuel though.